# Integrate Paypal IPN with Django

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have integrated Paypal IPN payment method in my Django project. I am using [django-paypal](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html) django package.

I am able to make payments using sandbox and it goes well but I don't get the transaction details back in my application for future reference (i.e. transaction ID, date, reference details etc.). I am sending below parameters while initiating payment.

```
paypal_dict = {
        "business": "xxxxxxxx@mail.com",
        "amount": subscriptions.price,
        "item_name": subscriptions.name,
        "invoice": subscriptions.invoice_no,
        "notify_url": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        "return_url": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('subscriptions:return_url')),
        "cancel_return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('subscriptions:cancel_return')),
        "custom": "premium_plan",  # Custom command to correlate to some function later (optional)
        # "landing_page": "billing",
        "paymentaction": "authorization",
        "first_name": company_profile.company_name,
        "last_name": "",
        "address1": company_profile.address_1,
        "address2": company_profile.address_2,
        "city": company_profile.city,
        "country": company_profile.country,
        "state": company_profile.state,
        "zip": company_profile.zip_code,
        "email": company_profile.email,
        "night_phone_a": company_profile.work_phone
    }
```

I read that IPN keeps sending response but not sure if I have missed to set any parameter.

I have checked that the **notify_url** is accessible from outside but I don't see that paypal call my notify_url.

Your valuable input will help us a lot. Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Comment: The point 4 in [documentation](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html) mentions `notify_url`. This url is the webhook URL which is called with the details of success and failure.

Comment: Your `notify_url` must be reachable from outside. Be aware that sandbox sometimes does not send IPN messages because it's absolutely broken. For instance, last week I received most of the IPN messages (with exception of refund notifications), but today I did not receive a single message and wasted the whole development day. My code was not changed at all. Paypal is just poison.

Comment: I have checked that the notify_url is accessible from outside but I don't see that paypal call my notify_url.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a static IP/Domain name, you will be better of using the actual url in your paypal dictionary, as if your server is sitting behind a firewall or proxy, you Paypal won't be able to find your server when sending the IPN. So change all the `request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('****')` to the actual url you specified in your app's urls.py.

Regarding testing, the [django-paypal's documentation](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html#testing) states that:

> If you are attempting to test this in development, using the PayPal sandbox, and your machine is behind a firewall/router and therefore is not publicly accessible on the internet (this will be the case for most developer machines), PayPal will not be able to post back to your view. You will need to use a tool like https://ngrok.com/ to make your machine publicly accessible, and ensure that you are sending PayPal your public URL, not localhost, in the notify_url, return and cancel_return fields.

When that's done, you have to link the signal paypal is going to send you (the IPN) to a function that will process it. To do so, create a file in your app called signals.py containing the following:

```py
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(valid_ipn_received)
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == "Completed":
           #Do something here, payement has been confirmed.
```

Then you have to connect this function to the signal Paypal will send. To do so, you can use the ready() method as suggested by [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/). To do so, add the following method to your apps.py file:

```py
class YourAppNameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'Yourappname'

    def ready(self):
        import yourappname.signals
```

Which makes sure that the link between the function and the signal is made when your django project is loaded.